# Clicking on given coordinates of element in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, mousemove, angularjs-e2e

I want to click on a specific location of my `canvas` element, so I wrote the following Protractor code:

```
var canvas = element(by.id("canvas"));

var clickCanvas = function(toRight, toBottom) { 
  browser.actions()
    .mouseMove(canvas, -toRight, -toBottom)
    .click();
}
```

`toRight`/`toBottom` are the numbers of pixels where the click should be made, relative the top left corner of my canvas.

However, the click does not seem to be executed at the given coordinates. I got the snippet from a [related question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8535/selenium-how-to-click-at-x-y-coordinates-on-mac-firefox-chrome) on the Software Quality Assurance & Testing stack exchange.

Can you confirm that this snippet works?
Can you suggest alternatives?

Comment: Have you looked into [`browser.executeScript()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript) at all?

Comment: You need to `.perform()` the action.

Answer (score 22):

I made this work, passing an object representing the coordinate as the second argument of `mouseMove`:

```
var canvas = element(by.id("canvas"));

var clickCanvas = function (toRight, toBottom) { 
    browser.actions()
      .mouseMove(canvas, {x: toRight, y: toBottom})
      .click()
      .perform();
};
```

Comment: @Olov as a consolation you get an up-vote from me ;-) does this work only with canvas elements or with any element?

Comment: @Besnik Well, it should work with any ElementFinder (look it up in the Protractor API reference if you haven't heared it before), thus should any element work fine.

Answer (score 3):

you missed out .perform()

`browser.actions().mouseMove(canvas, -toRight, -toBottom).click().perform();`

I use this a few times in my tests and confirm this works

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you have missed the `perform()` call:

```
 browser.actions()
  .mouseMove(canvas, -toRight, -toBottom)
  .click();  // < no .perform() HERE
```

This is one of the common mistakes when writing e2e tests in Protractor/WebDriverJS.

To prevent these errors from happening, there is a [`eslint-plugin-protractor`](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor) plugin to [`ESLint`](http://eslint.org/) that [would warn you](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/missing-perform.md) if `perform()` was no called on `browser.actions()` chain.